# Can we speed up Jenkins builds using our WebDAV repository as a shared Maven/Ivy cache?

Tags: sbt, cloudbees

Our CloudBees Jenkins SBT builds spend a lot of time re-downloading a considerable number of third-party jars any time we get a clean VM.  If we could download the jars once and never again into a shared cache, that would speed things up wonderfully.

It would seem our WebDAV repo would fit the bill.  The only issue I can think of is SBT's lock file, which *should* prevent contention between multiple builds, though I'm not sure if that works on a shared drive ([this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/simple-build-tool/KUb4B9YLRCg) suggests maybe not).  Might there be other issues that might catch us up?

An alternative might be to use our Cloudbees Artifactory server as a proxy for third-party jars, then mount Artifactory via WebDAV, though that sounds more complicated, and [this](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/concept.html) suggests Ivy might still copy files from WebDAV to its cache (which is still better than downloading to the cache).

Thanks.

Comment: Where are these artifacts stored when they are downloaded? Subsequent builds should reuse the same workspace cache. http://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/DEV/ImprovingBuildPerformance

Comment: Yeah, when we're given a VM we've used before. But when we're given a clean VM for a build, it doesn't have a cache.

Comment: This should be exceedingly rare and indicates a problem if not. Can you open a support ticket so that I can get additional details? (such as account name, etc)

Answer (score 0):

I heard people are saving the resulting artifacts of STB builds to Maven repo (I think this may help https://cloudbees.zendesk.com/entries/20836643-sbt-publish-to-repositories).

Note that the realm of the credentials must match exactly the realm of the server (https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/simple-build-tool/cloudbees/simple-build-tool/ovoxXM8fe7A/dAFQhdpcIvkJ).

Also be sure you create a folder before uploading the jars: afaik, webdav requires explicit directory creation.